# HTML5 native input type="time" element, how to locate pseudo element / style dropdown in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input, chromium

Chrome has introduced [an updated look to their styles](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html), including time and date picker elements that have a dropdown / overlay element to them.

I'm specifically attempting to style an `input type="time"` element. [Here is a demo of the native element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time). Worth noting is under Chrome 83 that it shows the updated dropdown page for selections.

[image: Chrome 83 Screenshot of Time Picker when selected]

Specifically, the dropdown shown above (the 00 and 00 text, with blue backgrounds, on an overlaid element) is what I would like to style or modify in some way.

I have enabled the shadow DOM option within the Google Chrome DevTools. I've been able to identify the pseudo elements for things like the input fields and icons and such, but not the dropdown.

It is difficult to provide further demonstrations or links since this is simply a native input. However, this is an example of the pseudo elements I can see on the basic native input.

[image: Screenshot showing the native time input element with the shadow DOM pseudo elements in the inspect view in Google Chrome]

My use-case is the app I'm using this for is for uses a dark UI color scheme, and this white popup element is very jarring. I prefer the native HTML input (especially with the keyboard accessibility of selecting the hour / minute / 12hour format quickly) over a custom timepicker.

Ideally I would not want to do anything too hacky here -- am I even approaching this in the right way? Want this not to break whenever Chrome updates.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the style of time or datepicker dropdown as per chrome FAQ

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome#how_do_i_change_the_appearance_of_the_date_picker

I suggest you to switch over to some custom or bootstrap controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the dropdown to be displayed, you could add a css rule to hide the icon, when you click that icon is when the dropdown gets displayed.

This rule should work

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
}
```