# Style the HTML5 input type="time" popup window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the popup window that comes out when the clock icon is pressed inside my text field, but so far I cannot find anything anywhere in regards. Is there a way to change the blue colour and the border into something else? I'm not entirely sure at this point since these styles aren't even appearing in my dev tools.

[image]

Comment: That popup window styling is determined by the vendor and/or the operation system itself, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: The pop-ups have pesudo class that will need to be styled.. have a look at this codepen 
https://codepen.io/stephenk/pen/poJordm

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455283/html5-native-input-type-time-element-how-to-locate-pseudo-element-style-dro

Comment: I already looked at all the questions, including the one that shows how to style the input time. No one shows or proves that what I posted can be actually styled. I have styled my input component but I just cannot style that window. Furthermore these pseudo classes aren't even showing in my dev tools. It shouldn't be marked as duplicated as it's not a duplicated question.